# Jquery Mobile and Ajax Panel not opening properly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile app that I'm using and I'm trying to get the right panel to open.  Its for notifications.  I have a feeling it has to do with with the ajax and it being done for multiple pages.  I have many pages in the document and I have assigned unique id's for each "myContent" div and also for the function toggleDiv.  For some reason when I click on the icon to open the panel it does nothing, and if i click it again it will open the panel then immediately close the panel.

Here is my code, any clues as to how this is happening?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   $("#"+divId).toggle();
$(document).ready(function(){
         $("#myContent").load("getnotes.php?name=<? echo $username; ?>");
    });
}
</script>

<!-- BEGIN PAGE 1 -->
<div data-role="page" id="feed" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="panel" id="settingspanel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay">
<!--LEFT SIDE PANEL CONTENT HERE-->

    </div>

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c" data-tap-toggle="false" data-id="foo1" style="padding-top: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #eccfb3; padding-bottom: 5px;">
        <a href="#settingspanel" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" class="icon-reorder icon-2x" style="background: none; margin-left: 20px;"></a>
        <center><img src="images/logo_app_white.png" height="25px"></center>

    <!--THIS IS THE BUTTON TO PUSH TO MAKE NOTIFICATIONS APPEAR-->  
        <a href="#myContent" data-ajax="false" onclick="toggleDiv('myContent');" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" class="icon-bell-alt icon-2x" style="background: none; margin-right: 20px;"></a><? echo $number; ?>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">   

        <!--THIS IS WHERE CONTENT FOR THE PAGE GOES-->


    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c" data-tap-toggle="false" data-id="foo1" style="border-top: 1px solid #eccfb3; padding-top: 5px;">
        <div data-role="navbar" style="background: #ce8339;">
                <!--ICONS FOR NAVIGATION BAR-->
        </div><!-- /navbar -->  
    </div>

        <!--HERE IS WHERE THE NOTIFICATIONS APPEAR-->
    <div data-role="panel" id="myContent" data-position="right" data-display="overlay">


    </div>


</div>

<!-- END PAGE 1 -->
```

Comment: Console log? Is there anything useful there? Could you provide a jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: jsfiddle isn't working.  I can tell you that when I delete the javascript code that gets the notifications the panel works fine.

Comment: Also when I click it the first time nothing happens but when I click it a second time it looks as if the panel is closing.  So it never shows it opening/opened, just closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your document ready out of the function. And the toggle() to show().

Change this

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   $("#"+divId).toggle();
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#myContent").load("getnotes.php?name=<? echo $username; ?>");
      });
   }
```

To this

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   $("#"+divId).show();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myContent").load("getnotes.php?name=<? echo $username; ?>");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OHajIvI/1/edit?html,output)